# How to position row of divs?

Tags: html, css

I'm currently working on a page that displays cards. My final row of cards has two cards centered because of my parent class `text-align center`. I am trying to manipulate the css for it start on the left side instead of centered. I've tried using `text-align left` in the div class but it only shifts the actual text in the card rather then the card itself. I've also tried setting my div with `col-md-3` but that shifted the spacing to far to the left.

I managed to get my [desired look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WiUL7.png)
 if I use two empty divs in order to push fill in the space.

Current look I'm [trying to fix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gr3ps.png)

here is my HTML code

```
                   <div class="card-panel">
                                    <div class="state">
                                           <svg class="icon icon-state-WI">
                                            <use xlink:href="#icon-state-WI"></use>
                                            </svg>
                                        </div>
                                    <div class="description-block">
                                        <h3>Wisconsin</h3>     
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="card-panel">
                                    <div class="state">
                                           <svg class="icon icon-state-WY">
                                            <use xlink:href="#icon-state-WY"></use>
                                            </svg>
                                        </div>
                                    <div class="description-block">
                                        <h3>Wyoming</h3> 
                                    </div>
                                </div>
```

css for `card-panel` and `description block`

```
.card-panel {
    background: #fefefe;

    border: 1px solid #d8ddea;

    box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.2),0 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.12),0 0 2px rgba(0,0,0,.14);

    border-radius: 5px;

    position: relative;

    display: inline-table;

    box-sizing: border-box;

    width: 360px;

    height: 135px;

    margin: 5px;

}

.description block {
position: relative;

display: inline-table;

text-align: left;

top: 15px;

padding-left: 75px;
}
```

Comment: We're likely going to need some CSS to make sure we can help you properly.

Comment: edited post to include css of card-panel

Answer (score 0):

If your divs have `display:inline` or `inline-block` then just add `text-align:left;` to **`parent`**.
If div displays are `flex`: use `margin-right:auto` in divs.
Hope it helps